# .Net CoreにおけるLinuxのメモリ使用量について

Tags: linux, .net, nginx, asp.net, azure

お世話になります。

.Net Core2.1で作ったアプリをAzure AppService on LinuxでWebサービスを運用しているのですが、Azure AppServiceのWindowsサーバーで運用していたときと比べメモリ使用量が平均で１０〜２０%増加しました。どちらもB1インスタンスなので全く同じスペックですし、サーバーを変えてからアプリケーションの変更は行なっていません。CPUの使用量は全く同じなので変動はありませんでした。

.Net CoreはLinuxサーバーだと若干メモリ使用量が増えるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

使用するライブラリーによりますが、Linuxサーバーだとメモリ使用量が増える場合が多いです。Windowsの方で主に開発されているソフトなので仕方がないと思います。処理速度も.Net Core2.0まではLinuxサーバーの方がはっきり遅かったですが、.Net Core2.1でかなり改善されました。

.NET Core は、windowsとLinuxでは実装に違いがあります。
参考: https://www.slideshare.net/tanakata/20170527-inside-net-core-on-linux

Comment: やっぱ皆さん同じような状況なんですね。2.2のブログをみたらHttpClientが大幅に改善されるようです。僕の環境だとHttpClient使うとメモリ使用量が大幅に増える傾向あるので、2.2で改善されるかもしれません。https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/10/17/asp-net-core-2-2-0-preview3-now-available/